# using select count based on partial data

Tags: sql

I'm currently making a call to an SQL database that counts all entries where the cell starts with NOI, but ends with anything else.

I thought using the below would work, but it doesn't seem to, anyone have any ideas? I know the % sign is the wildcard for foxpro, I don't know if this is the same in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT * FROM DIARY WHERE PTNOTE = 'NOI%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) if you want to use the wildcard characters:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DIARY WHERE PTNOTE LIKE 'NOI%'
```

(also added the parantheses around `*`)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DIARY
WHERE PTNOTE = 'NOI%';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the case even in Foxpro. You should use parentheses and "like":

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DIARY WHERE PTNOTE like 'NOI%'
```